# Does SSMS provide any default variables when running in SQLCMD mode?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

I would like to run a *parameterized* script meant for SQLCMD that contains variable expansions mainly for a database name. It appears that others are using hard coded `setvar:` statements at the top of scripts and forgetting to remove them before commit to source control because it simplifies running the script for them in SQL Server Management Studio.

I was thinking that in general if there are default values for the `$(SERVER)` or `$(DATABASE)` for example that it would cut most of the need for this as SSMS users could just select the database in the toolbar to provide a default value for such variables if they exist. This idea is to obvious to me to believe it doesn't already work this way.

So my question is whether such default variables already exist and if so is there any documentation on them because I haven't been able to find any?

Comment: That's just a different kind of hard-coding. One user may work with many servers (eg dev, staging, production) and one server can have many databases. SSMS is a *management* tool so hard-coding a single database isn't helpful. What you describe though *is* available in SSDT in the form of publishing profiles. For a development tool it *does* make sense to use predefined servers and settings.

Comment: As I can see it though SQLCMD mode offers no value in SSMS if the variables cannot be defined outside of the script itself. Maybe there are more use than variables that I'm overlooking that explain it's usefulness.